# How to real-time update React app with data from Django REST API

Tags: reactjs, django

I have a project that uses React for frontend and Django REST Framework for backend.Simply, when a new comment post for an article, I want to notify other users that are currently reading comments for that specific article.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You got two options here:

1. Asking for new comments with interval which I don't recommend cause request flood happens by frequently asking server "what's new on comments?".
2. SocketIO;

Make a SocketIO connection with your react app to the django, and make django to `emit` new comments when they are available, so `long polling` happens and whenever the data is available, it will be sent.

Comment: I also thought about first one and created a view in django api to ask for comment count with an article id and send it with an interval after componentDidMount,but it did not seem so efficient to me either.Can you send me a good reference source to understand sockets more clearly?

Comment: Socket.io is not related to Django. You should use [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for creating a web socket.

Comment: Django channel is the better option for socket, however you setup anything on django and socketIO can be one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use web push notifications or web socket api, my opinion is using web socket api